# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: for Firebase in Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I installed firebase by manually to my Xcode for storage data purpose. I followed README from DOCS and integrated. But, the issue is, after everything setup, I am getting following compiler errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  “_kFIRAppDiagnosticsErrorKey”, referenced from:
      +[FIRDiagnostics logDiagnostics:] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_0c03a82afb19aa444c2f4902b5217b60.o)
  “_kFIRAppDiagnosticsSDKNameKey”, referenced from:
      +[FIRDiagnostics logDiagnostics:] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_0c03a82afb19aa444c2f4902b5217b60.o)
  “_kFIRAppDiagnosticsSDKVersionKey”, referenced from:
      +[FIRDiagnostics logDiagnostics:] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_0c03a82afb19aa444c2f4902b5217b60.o)
  “_kFIRAppDiagnosticsFIRAppKey”, referenced from:
      +[FIRDiagnostics logDiagnostics:] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_0c03a82afb19aa444c2f4902b5217b60.o)
  “_kFIRServiceAuthUI”, referenced from:
      +[FIRDiagnostics populateLogProtoWithInstalledServices:] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_0c03a82afb19aa444c2f4902b5217b60.o)
      +[FIRDiagnostics mapFromServiceStringToTypeEnum:] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_0c03a82afb19aa444c2f4902b5217b60.o)
  “_kFIRAppDiagnosticsNotification”, referenced from:
      +[FIRDiagnostics load] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_0c03a82afb19aa444c2f4902b5217b60.o)
  “_FIRAuthStateDidChangeInternalNotificationAppKey”, referenced from:
      -[FAuthStateListenerWrapper authStateDidChangeNotification:] in FirebaseDatabase(FAuthTokenProvider_213581f9a756863b453764defdcb42ec.o)
  “_FIRAuthStateDidChangeInternalNotificationTokenKey”, referenced from:
      -[FAuthStateListenerWrapper authStateDidChangeNotification:] in FirebaseDatabase(FAuthTokenProvider_213581f9a756863b453764defdcb42ec.o)
  “_FIRAuthStateDidChangeInternalNotification”, referenced from:
      -[FAuthStateListenerWrapper initWithListener:app:] in FirebaseDatabase(FAuthTokenProvider_213581f9a756863b453764defdcb42ec.o)
  “_kFIRAppDiagnosticsConfigurationTypeKey”, referenced from:
      +[FIRDiagnostics logDiagnostics:] in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_0c03a82afb19aa444c2f4902b5217b60.o)
  “_utf8_nextCharSafeBody”, referenced from:
      -[FSRWebSocket _innerPumpScanner] in FirebaseDatabase(FSRWebSocket_221b45e2259898169b2d29adbe0c7833.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Only solution is upgrading Xcode to 9.0/9.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missed adding the `FirebaseCore` framework and `-licucore` to `OTHER_LD_FLAGS`

Comment: If I add that in Linked flags of Xcode build settings, its showing follow linker error ld: framework not found -licucore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)